# I don't know how to make this shape in python using "#'s" and "*'s"

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapes

I'm trying to create a simple python code that will create fairly simple shapes using "#'s" and "*'s" and I'm quite new to python and would like to only use `for loops` and the `range()` function. My code may be more complicated than it needs to be, but anyway, Heres my code so far:

```
Shapes = int(input("please enter the number size of the shape you want"))
sShapes = input("Would you like a square, triangle, Triangle 2 or Pyramid?")
s = 0
ss = Shapes + 1

##This is the code to make a square##
if sShapes == "Square":
    for i in range(0, Shapes):
        print('*'*Shapes)

##This is the code to make a triangle##
elif sShapes == "Triangle":
    for b in range(0, ss, 1):
        print('*'*(s+1)*b)

##This is the code that does not work##
elif sShapes == "T2":
    for c in range(ss,0,-1):
        print('#'*(s+1)*c, '*')
```

The code that does not work is supposed to look like this:

```
####*
###**
##***
#****
*****
```

Comment: I was trying something and just forgot to go over it and delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is my approach to print the above pattern

```
n = 6
for i in range(1, n):
    print("{}{}".format("#"*(n-i-1),"*"*i))

####*
###**
##***
#****
*****
```

You can pass `n` instead of absolute number

Comment: Thank you so much this has helped and I understand it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry also new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Just to tell you, accept answers until unless you get the solution or it helped in solving your problem. If there are multiple answers compare them and accept them. It's upto to you. Visit [help/faq](https://stackoverflow.com/help) section for more details.

Comment: Could someone explain to me why to use string formatting if `print("#"*(n-i-1)+"*"*i)` seems perfectly valid and more simple ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a single variable to control the loop:

```python
line_shape_number = 5 # Total number of shapes
for step in range(1, line_shape_number + 1):
    print '{}{}'.format('#' * (line_shape_number - step), '*' * step)
```